# How to use both dataset.select and selectExpr in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I want below mentioned data using Spark (2.2) dataset

```
Name    Age Age+5

A       10  15

B       5   10

C       25  30
```

I tried using the following :

```
dataset.select( 
        dataset.col("Name"), 
        dataset.col("Age),
        dataset.col( dataset.selectExpr("Age"+5).toString() )
       );
```

This throws exception as `Age` column not found.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`selectExpr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#selectExpr(java.lang.String...)) has the definition :

```
public Dataset<Row> selectExpr(String... exprs)
```

It takes varargs String as it's parameter. So, you can just use :

```
dataset.selectExpr( "Name", "Age", "Age+5" )
```

Comment: It's just like `select` but with different definition.